# links in table are not working

Tags: css, html

im new to this forum and i'm having some trouble with my code. I used a table for a navigation bar and after changing something, i couldn't get the links to work! They will not even allow me to right click and open in new tab. Below is a sample of my code.

```
<div class="bod">
            <table id="nav" cellspacing= 10px >
                <td><a href="index.html">Home</a></td>
                <td><a href="#about.html">About</a></td>
                <td><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></td>
                <td><a href="#contact.html">Contact us</a></td>
            </table>

        </div>

    <div class= "container">
    <table class="mid">

    <td><a  href="#" class="point" id ="left" onclick="prev(); return false;" ><img src="images/left.png" width="30px"></a></td>
    <td>    <div id="slider">
                <img id="1" src="images/1.jpg">
                <img id="2" src="images/2.jpg">
                <img id ="3" src="images/3.jpg">
                <img id ="4"src="images/4.jpg">
            </div>
    </td>
    <td>    
        <a  href="#" class="point" id="right" onclick="next(); return false;"><img src="images/right.png" width="30px"></a>
    </td>   

    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, accidentally hit post too soon. updated:

All  elements must belong to a `<tr>` element, like so:

```
<table id="nav" cellspacing= 10px >
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="index.html">Home</a></td>
      <td><a href="#about.html">About</a></td>
      <td><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></td>
      <td><a href="#contact.html">Contact us</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, you should not be using tables for presentational styling anyway; you should only be using them for tabular data.

Comment: Slipped on the post button before I got them in >.<

Comment: I deleted the comment once you added it. +1 for the presentational styling comment.

Comment: so in this case, what should i be using for my menu bar instead? and i tried again, this time with the <tr> tags but its still not working

At the same time, the other table is being used for my jquery slider to position the left and right navigation buttons, i'm wondering if that is causing the links to not work. I'm on chrome.

Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: That shouldn't be causing your links to not work. Do all of the links fail, or just some?

Comment: All of the links are not working, i suspect its got something to do with my css, but then again, the only css i have on the <a> tags are `text-decoration: none;`

Comment: <updated> I have changed the menu bar to use a list instead, and now its working. Thanks for all the replies! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that `about.html` link or `contact.html` link doesn't work, is because you have the # in front of them and make sure you are surrounding the `<td>` tags with a `<tr>` tag